# Varnish error : no backend connection

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I tried to install Varnish on my debian 7 with apache2.

But when i type www.mydomain.com:6081 to test the connection, i got a 503 error service unavaible.

Varnish log says :

```
 12 Hash         c www.mywebsite.com:6081
 12 VCL_return   c hash
 12 VCL_call     c pass pass
 12 FetchError   c no backend connection
 12 VCL_call     c error deliver
 12 VCL_call     c deliver deliver
 12 TxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
 12 TxStatus     c 503
```

My etc/varnish/default.vcl file :
(only one backend for now)

```
 backend site1 {
  .host = "92.243.5.12"; // ip adress for www.mydomain.com
  .port = "8080";
  .connect_timeout = 6000s;
  .first_byte_timeout = 6000s;
  .between_bytes_timeout = 6000s;
 }

# Default backend is set to site1
 set req.backend = site1;
```

My etc/default/varnish file :

```
   DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80
   -T localhost:6082
   -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
   -S /etc/varnish/secret
   -p thread_pool_add_delay=2
   -p thread_pools=4
   -p thread_pool_min=200
   -p thread_pool_max=4000
   -p cli_timeout=25
   -p session_linger=100
   -s file,/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin,1G"
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Is your site running on port 8080 at IP 92.243.5.12

Comment: The site is running on port 80, ip 92.243.5.12

Comment: In that case you need to change Varnish port to listen apart from 80 and check with same configuration or update ".port = "80"; to check via Varnish for site listening on port 80

Comment: Although it looks from those `DAEMON_OPTS` that Varnish is attempting to start on port 80 as well.

Answer (score -1):

In your conf file, you are making varnish listen to port 80 and you are sending requests to port 6081, that may be a reason.